# How to remove a table from a table using it's index

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am currently using/learning Corona SDK and I am trying to make a card game. A player has a set of unique cards that are drawn from their hand. These cards drawn should be removed from the deck. I am using a table of tables for this. I am having trouble removing the drawn cards. I am trying the below:

```
local tbl = cardTable[math.random(#cardTable)]  --tbl = random card drawn
table.insert(handTable, tbl)  --insert the table into a hand table
local indx = table.indexOf(cardTable, tbl) --get the index of the removed
table.remove(cardTable,indx) --remove that index
```

The cardTable is similar to the below:

cardTable = { {a,b,c}, {d,e,f}, {g,h,i}, ...}

This is inside a for loop iterating 5 times for a hand of 5 cards.

**Edit**

I realized that I made a mistake while inserting the cards into the cardTable. I inserted multiple copies of each card making it seem that it wasn't being removed. I should have checked this originally.

Comment: remove `handTable` element with it's index?

Comment: Looks reasonable. What *is* your trouble?

Answer (score 1):

You code looks good, so I assume it is some typo or set up error. However you're doing too much unnecessary work. You don't really need to find index - you've just generated/obtained it from user yourself. Why go looking for something you already know? You also don't need to separately retrieve value because `table.remove` returns value it removed. Just remove from `cardTable` and insert what you removed to `handTable` right away.

```
local indx = math.random(#cardTable) -- obtain draw and remove index in any way
table.insert(handTable, table.remove(cardTable, indx))
```

Comment: I do have a typo, it was with adding the elements to my table. I am inserting multiple copies of the same card to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and I dont have any problem even though it is similar to yours:

```
local t = { {"a","b","c"}, {d,e,f}, {g,h,i}}

local tbl = t[math.random(#t)]  --tbl = random card drawn
print(tbl)
local indx = table.indexOf(t, tbl) --get the index of the removed
print(indx)
table.remove(t,indx) --remove that index
print(t[indx])
```